# focus on the next element that has a 'tabindex' property

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I focus on the next element that has a 'tabindex' property

I need to this because all my inputs and selects have the same tabindex and do not have ids

```
$('form').keypress(function (event) {

    $("*:focus").nextAll('[tabindex]').focus(); //this is not working

});
```

---

```
<div>

    <input type="text"  tabindex="1" />
    <input " type="text"  tabindex="1" />
    <br /><br />
    <input  type="text"  tabindex="1" />

    <select  tabindex="1">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>

    <input type="text"  tabindex="1" />

</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can focus multiple elements at the same time

Comment: i dont want to focus on multiple elements, just the next one

Comment: try this: `$("*:focus").next('*[tabindex]').focus();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to select the `:first` element:

```
$(":focus").nextAll('[tabindex]:first').focus();
```

Notice also, you don't need the `*` at the start of the `:focus` selector. This is implied.

There's a full mockup here http://jsfiddle.net/QJQDP/1/

You've also got a typo (an extra `"`) in your second input.